# Android TextInputLayout legacy style

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

Android's new material TextInputLayout just supports two boxed and outlined style.

[image]

Is there any way to switch to legacy style (that was in support library)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
```